# Ranges as values in dictionary and using these in if else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, range

I am new to python basically, I want this dictionary:

```
ages = {
    "toddler" : range(0,2),
    "kid" : range(3,12),
    "teen" : range(13,19),
    "young adult" : range(20,25),
    "adult" : range(26,39),
    "middle-aged" : range(40,60),
    "old" : range(61,99)
}
```

I have a target_age variable which holds the random value in any of the keys in the above mentioned dictionary:

```
target_age = random.choice(list(ages))
```

my api is going to return an "age" which I want to compare if its in the range of the randomized "target_age" variable

How should I code my "if and else statement" if I want for example the returned_age is 25 and the target_age is "young adult" then it should satisfy the condition otherwise it should return false

Comment: You mean like `if returned_age in ages[target_age]` ?

Comment: By the way, `range` instances are end-exclusive, so you probably mean `range(0,3)`, `range(3,13)`, `range(13,20)` etc.

Comment: is if returned_age in ages[target_age] a valid python syntax? Basically, i want my if else to be if returned_age is in the range of the target_age defined in my age dictionary

Comment: `if returned_age in ages[target_age]` is valid syntax. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

`returned_age in ages[target_age]`, as mentioned by @khelwood above, sounds like it would accomplish what you want:

```
ages = {
        'toddler': range(0,3),
        'kid': range(3,13),
        'teen': range(13,20),
        'young adult': range(20,26),
        'adult': range(26,40),
        'middle-aged': range(40,61),
        'old': range(61,99)
        }

# generate a random target_age        
target_age = np.random.choice(list(ages))

# suppose the returned_age from the API is 25
returned_age = 25

print('target_age = ' + str(target_age))
print('returned_age = ' + str(returned_age))
print('returned_age in target_age? ' + str(returned_age in ages[target_age]))
```

Here is the output from one particular run:

```
target_age = old
returned_age = 25
returned_age in target_age? False
```

Comment: ok but what if I want to get the key from the dictionary based from the returned_age? like for example I want young adult to be returned if the returned_age is 25

Comment: Not sure if I should suggest you open a new question for this, but... You could use a list comprehension to get the target_age: `actual_target_age = {k for k,v in ages.items() if returned_age in v}`